# How to show that the set of polynomials is dense?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, polynomials, bergman-spaces

Consider a norm on the space of analytic functions $\|f\|=\int_{\mathbb C} \frac{|f|}{e^{|z|}} \, dz$. Is the set of polynomials dense in the space of analytic functions with bounded norm?

My guess is yes, but it is really hard to show. If we have uniform convergence of the power series, then it will be easy.